# Output time using xlswrite

Tags: excel, matlab

I am attempting to create a timestamp (date, or date and time) using either

```
t=now;
```

or

```
t=date;
```

and when it outputs using `xlswrite`, the date or time and date become spread throughout a half dozen cells. I've tried converting into arrays and vectors and it has same output.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only give a string to xlswrite, MATLAB will put each char in one cell. To get an entire string into one Excel cell you have to make a cell out of it in matlab. 'date' returns a string with todays date, so that part is easy

```
xlswrite('test',date); % one char in each
xlswrite('test2',{date}); % entire date in [1,1]
```

'now' on the other hand is the number of days (float point for hours and so on) since 0000-01-01 00:00. Writeing this is a little bit tricky since MATLAB uses 0000-01-01 as reference while Excel takes 1900-01-01. so you have to not only put now in a cell but also make a string out of it before passing it to Excel.
If you dont you either end up with a date in the sweet year 3916 or there will be just the MATLAB datenum as double which is a number around 730000. Which of the 2 happens is dependent on your MATLAB and Excel Version and on the fact what else your write in that .xls. but as they are equally unwanted always go for datestr:

```
mycell=cell(2,1)
mycell(1)={now}
mycell(2)={datestr(now)}
xlswrite('test3',mycell)
```